# How to use S3 as maven repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3

I am unable to deploy maven artifacts to S3.

I receive AccessDenied exception even though I have write access to the bucket.

When I run `mvn deploy -DskipTests`, I get following error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 5CFBE8472B760710; S3 Extended Request ID: cxvn4bs9sg2hNEZRbno2dxocwSj8i6jCSNSQtsZL2H7h2y/cY2koFhExrGv3mACLK+kfcxHfKkg=), S3 Extended Request ID: cxvn4bs9sg2hNEZRbno2dxocwSj8i6jCSNSQtsZL2H7h2y/cY2koFhExrGv3mACLK+kfcxHfKkg=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1630)
```

S3 Request triggered by wagon plugin:

```
>> PUT /release/ HTTP/1.1
>> Host: inuka-mvn-repo.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
>> x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
>> Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAUMQWI47EFQZPBQW3/20191018/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-retry;content-length;content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=b20a1e2fb100eae4b70d7c0922fde9164bc7326d02074627e54d860359d8b298
>> X-Amz-Date: 20191018T145734Z
>> x-amz-acl: public-read
>> User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.276 Mac_OS_X/10.13.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.60-b23 java/1.8.0_60
>> amz-sdk-invocation-id: 47ea0bcd-c021-6d48-2547-f9a276c055cd
>> amz-sdk-retry: 0/0/500
>> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>> Content-Length: 0
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "PUT /release/ HTTP/1.1"
>> "Host: inuka-mvn-repo.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
>> "x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"
>> "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAUMQWI47EFQZPBQW3/20191018/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-retry;content-length;content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=b20a1e2fb100eae4b70d7c0922fde9164bc7326d02074627e54d860359d8b298"
>> "X-Amz-Date: 20191018T145734Z"
>> "x-amz-acl: public-read"
>> "User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.276 Mac_OS_X/10.13.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.60-b23 java/1.8.0_60"
>> "amz-sdk-invocation-id: 47ea0bcd-c021-6d48-2547-f9a276c055cd"
>> "amz-sdk-retry: 0/0/500"
>> "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
>> "Content-Length: 0"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive"
>> ""
```

S3 Response

```
<< "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
<< "x-amz-request-id: 83C798E7B7B523ED"
<< "x-amz-id-2: 6QylxeiERpjXVuThC0VXYqCGSL9+pWqw5Kdi/1PpI+ly1eBMxYY+byB59T7yGLf2D5vPOLTLAPA="
<< "Content-Type: application/xml"
<< "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
<< "Date: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 14:57:33 GMT"
<< "Server: AmazonS3"
<< ""
<< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
<< x-amz-request-id: 83C798E7B7B523ED
<< x-amz-id-2: 6QylxeiERpjXVuThC0VXYqCGSL9+pWqw5Kdi/1PpI+ly1eBMxYY+byB59T7yGLf2D5vPOLTLAPA=
<< Content-Type: application/xml
<< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<< Date: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 14:57:33 GMT
<< Server: AmazonS3
e kept alive for 60000 MILLISECONDS
<< "f3"
<< "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
<< "<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>83C798E7B7B523ED</RequestId><HostId>6QylxeiERpjXVuThC0VXYqCGSL9+pWqw5Kdi/1PpI+ly1eBMxYY+byB59T7yGLf2D5vPOLTLAPA=</HostId></Error>"
<< "0"
<< ""
```

I use `com.github.platform-team:aws-maven` for uploading to S3

```
<build>
    ...
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.github.platform-team</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

This is my maven repo configuration

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.inuka</id>
        <url>s3://*****-mvn-repo/release</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I have write access to s3 from command line:

```
halils-mbp:inuka-be halil$ aws s3 cp pom.xml s3://inuka-mvn-repo
upload: ./pom.xml to s3://inuka-mvn-repo/pom.xml
```

Can anybody help me, why maven wagon plugin `com.github.platform-team:aws-maven` cannot upload to S3?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @karthikeayan See my answer - hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the Maven S3 wagons out there, including the one referenced in the question, don't seem to support writing to buckets with private permissions out of the box. The result is that even if your IAM policies are fine, and your authentication details are fine, you'll get a 403 when it comes to that `PUT` call.

The only one I've found which works out of the box for private buckets is the [Allogy wagon](https://github.com/Allogy/maven-s3-wagon):

```
<build>
...
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.allogy.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
...
</build>
```

Comment: i'm using this but still getting error can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have miss configured your S3 policy or m2 setting's server id doesn't match with your pom distributionManagements, also have both `snapshotRepository` and `repository`

example:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>YOUR_BUCKET_NAME-snapshot</id>
        <url>s3://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>YOUR_BUCKET_NAME-release</id>
        <url>s3://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/release</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I've found this maven extension use-full. It's build on top of apache wagon, link:
https://github.com/ehsaniara/maven-repository-aws-s3

you can start from : https://github.com/ehsaniara/maven-repository-aws-s3#configure-by-aws-console

Setp1: you create s3 policy with the following permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then create a IAM user and attach that policy.

on your `.m2/setting` add both `snapshot` and `release` server ids

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    ...
    ...
    <server>
      <id>YOUR_BUCKET_NAME-snapshot</id>
      <username>AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID</username>
      <password>AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY</password>
      <configuration>
        <region>AWS_REGION</region>
        <publicRepository>false</publicRepository>
      </configuration>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>YOUR_BUCKET_NAME-release</id>
      <username>AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID</username>
      <password>AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY</password>
      <configuration>
        <region>AWS_REGION</region>
        <publicRepository>false</publicRepository>
      </configuration>
    </server>
    ....
    ....
  </servers>
</settings>
```

then add the following extension in to your pom

```
 <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.github.ehsaniara</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-repository-aws-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made one that supports AWS SSO (OIDC auth) that uses the second version of the SDK. Maybe it can be useful for someone that found this question when they, as I did, searched for such functionality.

https://github.com/embriq-nordic/aws-oidc-s3-maven-wagon

```
<extension>
    <groupId>io.github.embriq-nordic</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-oidc-s3-maven-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</extension>
```

Since it uses the second version of the SDK it uses the credentials provider chain used by that one.

Of course, you still need create a policy/role as described in Jay Ehsaniara's answer.